# Solutions Airy function (Bleistein)

Tags: complex-analysis, airy-functions

I'm studying the Airy functions but i have some problem with the solutions.

Looking a "Asymptotic Expansions of Integrals by Bleistein and Handelsman" pag. 52

[image]

How i get the (2.5.9) is clear. I don't understand:

- Why we have to take $f_2(z) = e^{-2i\pi/3} Ai(ze^{-2i\pi/3}) $. The exponential outside is clear, but why i have $e^{-2i\pi/3}$ inside Ai? (same for $f_3(z)$)
- The (2.5.12). Why is $Bi = i[f_2(z) - f_3(z)]$?

Comment: If you write the integral over $C_2$ for example and make a change of integration variables, you can turn the integral to an integral over $C_1$ (using symmety relations between the contours). Now you can use (2.5.9) to identify $f_2$ in terms of Ai. As for Bi, that is just a definition. Since all the $f_i$'s satisfy the same linear homogeneous ODE, Bi also satisfies it (it is a linear combination of linearly independent soluations).

Comment: Bit more details: $$
f_2 (z) = \frac{1}{{2\pi i}}\int_{C_2 } {e^{ - s^3 /3 + sz} ds}  = \frac{{e^{ - 2\pi i/3} }}{{2\pi i}}\int_{C_2 } {e^{ - (se^{2\pi i/3} e^{ - 2\pi i/3} )^3 /3 + se^{2\pi i/3} e^{ - 2\pi i/3} z} d(e^{2\pi i/3} s)}  \\ = \frac{{e^{ - 2\pi i/3} }}{{2\pi i}}\int_{C_1 } {e^{ - t^3 /3 + te^{ - 2\pi i/3} z} dt}  = e^{ - 2\pi i/3} \operatorname{Ai}(ze^{ - 2\pi i/3} ).
$$